# Adding a New Column in a DF based on muiltiple conditions (Beginner)

Tags: python, dataframe

I currently have a data based e.g. below:

[Link To Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clJI7.jpg)

I would like to add a new column, to the right of "Equity" called "Exposure".

```
If the Quantity >=0 then "Exposure" = df[Equity] - df[market value].
If the Quantity <0 then "Exposure" = df[Equity] - (-1*df[Market Value])
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Help us help you. Please post a paste out of your data IN TEXT, and what you want the output to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for `df.transform`:

```
df['Exposure'] = df.transform(lambda x: (x['Equity'] - x['Market Value']) if x['Quantity'] > 0 else (x['Equity'] + x['Market Value']), axis=1)
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thank you! Great response! It works beautifully. I will study up LAMBDA further and comfortable with it.

Comment: @OPM_OK No problem. Remember, you can always _accept_ an answer if it helped. :)